# Concise way to remove all empty results from a series of shifting lists and keep only the first string

Tags: python

'm itereting over many files with lists. The lists have a different string each time that can be at any position. The other members are empty.

What's the most concise and pythonic way to keep only the first string. I say the first because even if there are more than on string I want the first one that appears.

My list:

```
lst = ['', 'some string', '']
```

but could also be:

```
lst = ['some other different string', '', '']
```

or:

```
lst = ['yet another string', 'apple', '', '']
```

and so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something terse (which is not necessarily pythonic), you can do:

```
first = next(filter(None, lst))
```

this is about equivalent to the equally reasonable:

```
def first_non_empty(lst):
    for x in lst:
        if x:
            return x
    raise ValueError("List has no nonempty elements")
```